# An updating loading bar while the program is doing something else

Tags: python, progress-bar

I have a loading bar and I want to make it that it will update while the program is doing something. Here’s my code:

```
start = False
import sys
progress = 0
def bar():
    if not start == True:
        print('loading...')
        start = True
    progress += 1
    bar = '\b' * progress
    msg = ''.join('[' + bar + '] ' str(progress))
    sys.stderr.write(msg)
#i want here that he starts
#and that it become a while true loop
#but that i do something here while de loop is going
# and that i can say here something as break
```

My results are nothing and I want that it will show a becoming bigger bar while a other process is going

is it possible to use threading at this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't exactly understand your question except that you want a real-time progress bar.

I guess python's tqdm is a great tool for such progress bars.

Official Documentation :: https://tqdm.github.io/

```
>>> from tqdm import tqdm
>>> for i in tqdm(range(10000000), total=10000000):
...     pass
... 
100%|██████████████████████████| 10000000/10000000 [00:03<00:00, 2665344.22it/s]
```

PS: I could've commented this tool but dont have the reputation to do so :)